# $_SESSION variable not saving on page refresh or new page

Tags: php, cookies, localhost, session

So I have a form that allows the user to select a city. Once selected, this city is then saved to a $_SESSION variable as such : `$_SESSION['city_selected'] = $_POST['location_select'];`

This works fine once selected. When I `var_dump($_SESSION);` I see my variable perfectly on after selecting the city and the page refreshing.

Then, if I move to a different page or refresh the same page - the `var_dump();` returns `NULL`

I can't seem to figure this out. My PHP session ID doesn't change.

I am using WAMP on a local server, and session files are saving in the \tmp folder.

Am I missing something? What the heck is happening?

Comment: Make sure that you have `session_start();` at the top of all your scripts.

Comment: PHP sessions don't work on a lot of hosts and are incompatible with many features such as CDNs and page caching plugins because of how they work. PHP sessions also rely on a session id cookie so they can't be sued to bypass cookie regulations/laws/banners

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `session__start() ;` at the top of that other page? You always need to retrieve session data when changing pages.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in case it helps others. I was trying to store a complex object in the session, and it wasn't serializing. The "cannot serialize" error only appeared in logs when I wrote the session manually with `session_write_close()`, so for a long time I couldn't see that this was the issue.
If one part of the session won't serialize, it seems that the whole session write fails.